# How to move sync's data to another partition after run Bitcoind for a while?

Tags: bitcoind, linux, storage

I have download a new bitcoin package from official site. And then I ran it with `daemon` mode also with default configuration (Default means not `bitcoin.conf` file was created in `~/.bitcoin/.bitcoin.conf`). After ran 2 hours. I got stuck, and the process exit. When I checked my disk with:

```
df -lh
```

And then, I got those:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        20G   20G  118M 100% /
devtmpfs        3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.9G  233M  3.6G   6% /run
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vdb        800G  7.7G  792G   1% /data
tmpfs           783M     0  783M   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           783M     0  783M   0% /run/user/1001
```

And I googled for a while, but could't find a good way to move all sync's data to the `/dev/vdb`. I understand what my mistake came from, but I just fixed it by move data and then put a new configuration with `--data-dir=/dev/vdb`. and then keep sync it.

So, How do I reach that?

Comment: Rather than adding —data-dir to the config file, try starting bitcoind by running `bitcoind —data-dir=[your directory] [whatever other commands you want to run]`.

Comment: @chytrik Did you mean run the bitcoind with `--data-dir` like `./bitcoind --data-dir=/data `?

Comment: ^yea! Sorry I accidentally submitted my comment half-written, and had to edit to add the rest. Mobile keyboard problems :p

Comment: Anyway, Thank you so much. And could you also point me how to move the old data to the new place?

Comment: best way on unixoide systems to copy data over different media is rsync in a terminal. I usually go "rsync -rpogDtW <source_dir> <target_dir>". Further details are not bitcoin relevant, and should then be asked in another stackexchange forum.

Answer (score 0):

I have try to ran the `bitcoind -data-dir=/data/db -daemon` , but it's not write the data to the path where I specify. Actually, The right way to do that with :

```
bitcoind -datadir=/data/db -daemon
```

**Attention**

```
   -data-dir --> -datadir
```